# Android switch between Login and MainActivity

Tags: android

I have 2 Activities.
MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{

    private SharedPreferences settings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        settings = getPreferences(0);

        if (settings.getBoolean("firstStart", true)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        }
}
```

LoginActivity which is only called at the first time the App is starting. It calls the saveClass() Method:

```
private void saveClass() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putBoolean("firstStart", false);

        editor.commit();

        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.toast_login_success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
```

And now the problem:

The LoginActivity is always started. So I guess something with the preferences is not working fine. 
What did I make wrong or what do I have to do that this code works?

Comment: the preference save looks fine since you are commiting the changes, what about your logic for starting the activity?

Comment: could you post the code of getPreferences(0);

Comment: Maybe there is the problem. I don't know. I think this should normally work but it looks like that ```settings.getBoolean("firstStart", true)``` always returns true. and this should only be if the entry ```firstStart``` is not in the preferences

Comment: instead of using getPreferences try using `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);`

Comment: @StefanBeike http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `getPreferences` try using

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```